# How does KDE's Dolphin sort files?

Tags: dolphin

I have a camera that names files with hexadecimal digits (not sure why, but that's a different question). When I download the files to my Kubuntu PC and open the directory with Dolphin, the order is "unexpected".

For example, let's say I have the following files (extensions dropped for simplicity) created by the camera in this order:

- mov001
- mov002
- mov00A
- mov010
- mov01A

Dolphin sorts them out as such:

- mov00A
- mov001
- mov01A
- mov002
- mov010

I find this very strange; e.g., why would mov002 or mov010 come after mov01A?

On the other hand, if I do `ls` in Bash, they appear in the expected order.

What confused me even further is that Dolphin will make the following sorting choices:

- 1 (literally, a file named just "1")
- 2
- A

but

- 00A
- 001
- 002

So, how does sorting work exactly?

**System**:

- KDE Plasma 5.5.5
- Qt 5.5.1
- Kernel 4.13.0-41-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Unfortunately it is the way that each file manager is.  I was helping someone before on it and I never wrote an answer but I did find a couple of file managers that were capable of listing the files the correct way:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011584/how-to-sort-files-files-alphabetically-rather-than-numerically-in-file-manager?rq=1

Comment: It's there in 18.04. But see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004209/f2-rename-shortcut-stopped-working-on-kde-5-plasma-desktop#comment1625073_1004209

Comment: Please take a look at the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1195505/590937).