# How to change how files are sorted in different folders in Dolphin?

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

On Kubuntu 19.10, I would like the Downloads folder to be sorted by date modified, and other folders to be sorted alphabetically. However, whenever I sort the Downloads folder by Date Modified, every other folder is sorted that way as well. How do I set a custom setting only for the Downloads folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As first step, you may have to go to:

```
Control > Dolphin preferences > General > Behaviour > View (Old versions of Dolphin)

☰ > Configure > Configure Dolphin... > General > Behaviour > View (New versions of Dolphin)
```

and mark

```
Remember properties for each folder (Old)

Remember display style for each folder (New)
```

[image: UI of Dolphin demonstrating "Remember display style for each folder"]

Then go to:

```
Control > Adjust view properties (Old)

☰ > More > View > Adjust View Display Style... (New)
```

In the window that pops up, adjust the parameters as you want and then select:

```
Apply to: Current folder
```

or

```
Apply to: Current folder and sub-folders
```

[image: UI of Dolphin demonstrating "Apply to: Current folder and sub-folders"]

Comment: I don't have the "Apply to" option

Comment: Tell me if this helps: go to `Dolphin preferences > General > Behaviour > View >` and mark `Remember properties for each folder`. Then you should see the `Apply to` option.

Comment: Yes, it has worked! Thank you very much